# Pdf opening Error in Acrobat?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

When i add footer in pdf using `iTextSharp` and c# pdf display error at open time in acrobat.

My code is:

```
base.OnEndPage(writer, document);
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageSize = document.PageSize;

float GCEStart = pageSize.Width - 200;
float CapitalNovusStart = pageSize.Width - 175;
float ReportGeneratedStart = pageSize.Width - (pageSize.Width - 20);
float eZREviewStart = pageSize.Width - (pageSize.Width - 130);

float offset = 0;
offset = (document.PageSize.Width - template.Width) / 2;

cb.SetRGBColorFill(128, 128, 128);
cb.BeginText();
cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);
cb.SetTextMatrix(ReportGeneratedStart, 15);
cb.ShowText("Report has been generated by");
cb.AddTemplate(template, offset, 20);
cb.EndText();

cb.SetRGBColorFill(255, 192, 0);
cb.BeginText();
cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 16);
cb.SetTextMatrix(eZREviewStart, 15);
cb.ShowText("eZReview");
cb.AddTemplate(template, offset, 20);
cb.EndText();

cb.SetRGBColorFill(128, 128, 128);
cb.BeginText();
cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);
cb.SetTextMatrix(GCEStart, 10);
cb.ShowText("GOVERNANCE | COMPLIANCE | E-DISCOVERY");
cb.AddTemplate(template, offset, 20);
cb.EndText();

cb.SetRGBColorFill(255, 192, 0);
cb.BeginText();
cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 16);
cb.SetTextMatrix(CapitalNovusStart, 20);
cb.ShowText("CAPITAL NOVUS");
cb.AddTemplate(template, offset, 20);
cb.EndText();
```

I've been searching about this there is issue in `setTextMatrix` and I don't know how is set this code work proper pdf generate fin ebut its display error when i open pdf file in acrobat

Comment: You add templates inside text objects. This is invalid.

Comment: You should add this as an answer so that we can up-vote it.